# Run postgres in container using podman

Tags: postgresql, containers, podman

I want to run postgres in podman container
I download the image using `podman pull docker.io/library/postgres:14`, I also download version 16 and latest

I tried to run a container from the image using

```bash
podman run 4d8f13d97fae --name base \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=base \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=base \
  -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust \
  -p 5432:5432
```

but I receive the following error

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

I believe I set all needed environment variables, any clue whats wrong

Comment: It might just be that you need the options before the image-name. Check `man podman-run`.

Comment: You **absolutely** need podman (or docker!) options **before** the image name; otherwise they are considered options to be passed in to your container as the `CMD`.

Answer (score 2):

The image name should be at end of podman command like:

Example:

```
podman run --name base \ 
-e POSTGRES_USER=base \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=base \
-e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust \
-p 5432:5432 \
postgres:14
```